# Nearby api on Android things powered Raspberry Pi 3 B device

Tags: android, iot, android-things, google-nearby

I am trying to use android nearby connection api in android things. But i am getting this error **com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device.** while advertising from android things.

Here is my gradle file of android things app:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
```

I am using latest version of android things in raspberry pi. And here is my menifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />

    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Why i am getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I got it working with:

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:15.0.1'
```

You can check the source code from the project here: https://github.com/plattysoft/Beret

Comment: After Using 15.0.1 version i get following exception:  

     com.google.android.gms.persistent W/ChimeraUtils: Module 
     com.google.android.gms.nearby has empty metadata display_name_string_id

Comment: Advertising from android things is successful but cannot discover the endpoint from android device.

Answer (score 0):

A few potential error sources here:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
```

Play Services on Android Things isn't updated over-the-air, so the library you're using should match the bundled version, which should be 12.5.20.

Your issue sounds similar to [this one](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/issues/51). Are you using the API the same way as described in the issue?